# How do I translate "舒服不如倒着，好吃不过饺子" in English?

Tags: translation

This phrase means

> There is nothing more comfortable than lying down. There is nothing more
>   delicious than jiaozi.

I would rather find more local version. Thank you guys.

I love dumplings quite much. :)

Comment: Is this even a chinese idiom? If so can you explain what it means in Chinese?

Comment: As you can see I did a literal translation of this saying. :)
It describles dumpling could be the most delicious food.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about English language that doesn't require any knowledge about Chinese language.

Comment: I think that it should probably be migrated to ELL.

Answer (score 1):

As with most idioms, there's a couple ways to translate this non-literally.

If you want to go the old fashioned route, you can maybe quote from the Bible like:

> There is nothing better for a man, than that he should eat and drink, and that he should make his soul enjoy good in his labour. ([Ecclesiastes 2:24](http://biblehub.com/ecclesiastes/2.htm))

Or maybe the Spanish idiom:

> A full stomach makes a happy heart. (barriga llena, corazón contento)

You could of course modify those to be about dumpling specifically: i.e. A stomach full of dumplings makes a happy heart.

Or you can just try something from yourself:

> Life doesn't get better than relaxing in bed and eating delicious dumplings.